# How to change the name of the submit button in google inbox actions review button

Tags: google-schemas

I was able to implement review button for the feedback using google inbox actions. However the submit button on the feed back says "Publish on gmail.com". How can I change that ? I tried adding "name": "Post Review" here and there like after  "@type": "HttpActionHandler",    but nothing helped.

Below is the JSON-LD I am using

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",  
  "action": {
    "@type": "ReviewAction",   
    "review": {
      "@type": "Review",
      "name": "test",
      "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Feedback"
      },
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "worstRating": "1"
      }
    },
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",   
      "url": "http://test.com/Feedback/Submit?EntityID=55e832685cd44e8ba6da1524",
      "requiredProperty": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "name": "review.reviewRating.ratingValue"
      },
      "optionalProperty": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "name": "review.reviewBody"
      },
      "method": "http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/POST"
    }
  },
  "description": "We hope you liked our service. Please tell us about it."
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're sending an email to yourself from your personal Gmail account. In order to change the "Publish on gmail.com" in to a domain of your preference, you would have to send from that domain.

For example, if Amazon sent you a Review Action email from orders@amazon.com it would say "Publish on Amazon.com." So, unfortunately, you won't be able to get this unless your email (ex. ravi@mycompany.com) is whitelisted for Review Actions, once you're whitelisted, you should will see "Publish on mycompany.com."

You can find more information on registering to be whitelisted for Gmail schemas here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google?hl=en

Hope this helps you out Ravi.

Comment: I want to change the complete text something like "Post Reviews" or "Submit". Isn't that possible ?

Comment: Like in the example https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/review-action image has a customized text on button that says "Post Review"

Comment: @RaviA. Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately, you can't modify the action button. It will either be "review" or "rate."

Comment: Actually I am talking about the submit review button which says "Post Review" on the bottom right hand side.

Comment: @RaviA. To my knowledge, you can't modify the "Post Review" button on the bottom right hand side.